# My phone work but screen is black

Tags: samsung

My phone open normally and it works , but the screen is black!

My phone is galaxy j3 with OP 5.1.1 , Help please ! :(

Comment: What happened prior to this?  By working normally, do you mean that you can receive calls?  Can you connect to it via ADB?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

> 1.) Your phone might be in a hanged state. Try a "adb reboot" command by attaching your device to your computer, however, you need to have developer options enabled or else it wouldn't work.
>
> 2.) LCD digitizer (a hardware module responsible for rendering Android's UI) is gone (short-circuited). You need to get it replaced.
>
> 3.) Do a hard-reboot (into any mode: recovery, bootloader/fastboot/any-other-samsung-proprietary-alternative-mode).

If you have tried every possible way to make your display come back, clearly the digitizer is short-circuited. Get it replaced (warranty covers that for free*)

* - Conditions applied.